# Why is the melting point of lactic acid higher than pyruvic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols, melting-point

I have a quick question about pyruvic acid and lactic acid, which I think I know the answer too but I'm unsure.

> The melting point of lactic acid is said to be higher than that of pyruvic acid despite very similar molecular masses.

Is this because lactic acid has 2 $\ce{OH}$ groups, and pyruvate only has 1, thus there are twice as many hydrogen bonds between lactic acid molcules that must be broken for the substance to melt?

Comment: Do you men boil or melt?

Comment: @A.K. I know it sounds weird, and it seems way more intuitive to ask about the boiling point, but that literally is what the question asks.

Answer (score 4):

Your analysis is practically correct but not quite — more due to technical reasons. You said:

> Is this because lactic acid has 2 $\ce{OH}$ groups, and pyruvate only has 1 […]?

You probably know the structures of both; they both include a $\ce{COOH}$ group which you apparantly counted as a hydroxy group. You should not do that; the carboxy group ($\ce{COOH}$) has different properties than a lone hydroxy group ($\ce{CR2OH}; \ce{R} \ne \ce{OX}$). The most obvious is the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value which differs by about $10$ logarithmic units.

So you should say that lactic acid has higher melting and boiling points becuase it contains **a** (or: one) hydroxy group while pyruvic acid has a carbonyl group in the same position.

Comment: So basically the presence of the OH causes there to be hydrogen bonding between lactic acid molecules, which don't exist between pyruvate molecules due the the presence of a Carbonyl group instead.

Comment: @frostedcake Well, the carboxy group does hydrogen bond, too; but you can form more hydrogen bonds per molecule with lactic acid than with pyruvic acid.